# asp.net: url routing and dropdownlist on same page

Tags: asp.net, url, drop-down-menu

I have an .aspx page with a dropdownlist on it (just ASP.NET Pages **not** MVC). After making a choice the page gets a postback via a button and a gridview appears using the control value as a parameter. Is it possible to apply url routing and show the value of the dropdownlist in the page url? And if so the next question is how to do it.
Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is solved:

1. The main problem was the fact that the windows.location caused a soft postback. This means that there are three postbacks with this code: first starting-up the page, second filling out the dropdownlist and third the navigate javascript.
2. This produces the following code:

   Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

   ```
   If ddlBerg.SelectedValue.Length = 0 Then
       DetailsView1.Visible = False
       GridView1.Visible = False
       line1.Visible = False
   Else
       DetailsView1.Visible = True
       GridView1.Visible = True
       line1.Visible = True

       'zorg dat navigate() beschikbaar is onder ajax
       If (Not ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("navigate")) Then
           Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "navigate", "navigate();", True)
       End If

   End If

   If ddlBerg.SelectedValue.Length > 0 Then
       Session("Berg") = ddlBerg.SelectedValue
       Session("Bergnaam") = ddlBerg.SelectedItem.Text
   End If

   'wordt gebruikt door 3e rondje Page_Load: navigate() geeft softe postback (een soort crosspage)
   If Not Page.IsPostBack() And Session("Berg") <> "" Then
       ddlBerg.SelectedValue = Session("Berg")
       ddlBerg.DataBind()
       lblSelectedId.Text = String.Format("Selected Id of ddlBerg is: {0}", ddlBerg.SelectedItem.Value)
       DetailsView1.DataBind()
       GridView1.DataBind()
       DetailsView1.Visible = True
       GridView1.Visible = True
       line1.Visible = True
   End If

   titel1.Text = "Tour de France: alle Beklimmingen van " + ddlBerg.SelectedItem.Text
   ```

   End Sub

Second the code on the page itself regarding the button (not in the updatepanel otherwise it won't work):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPostBack" CssClass="Button" Text="Asp Button" runat="server" />

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSelectedId"></asp:Label>
```

Third the navigate() javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function navigate() {
        var e = document.getElementById("ddlBerg");
        //get the name
        var selectedID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        var current = window.location.href;
        // prevent concatenating ?Bergnaam
        var href_split = current.split("?");
        current = href_split[0];
        //construct the new url
        var togo = current + "?Bergnaam=" + selectedID.toString();
        //chain it to the location
        window.location = togo;
    }
</script>
```

Alltogether this works: I hope someone will benefit!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the query string from a postback.

however you can do a GET request with the value of dropdown instead of a POST.

for example replacing button click with a hyperlink and from https://stackoverflow.com/  go to http://stackoverflow.com?Dropid=5
than in pageload , if you have a "Dropid" in your query string run a call to then method that plays the role of button click.

**Edit**

**Asp.Net markup**

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drop" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="One"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Two"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Three"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <input type="button" onclick="navigate();" value="style this better" />

    <br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSelectedId"></asp:Label>

    <script>
        function navigate() {
            var e = document.getElementById('drop');
            var selectedId = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            var current = window.location.href;

            var togo = current + "?dropId=" + selectedId.toString();
            window.location = togo;
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

**than in code behind :**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["dropId"] != null)
            {
                doWork(Request.QueryString["dropId"].ToString());
            }
        }

        private void doWork(string selectedId) 
        {
            lblSelectedId.Text = string.Format("Selected id of drop is :{0}", selectedId);
        }

        protected void btnRedirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /* these will throw error since collection is readonly */
            //HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Add("DropId", drop.SelectedValue);
            //HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["DropId"] = drop.SelectedValue;
        }
```

hope it helps...

Comment: I tried this:         <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="Button" ToolTip="Selecteer Berg"
        CommandArgument='<%# ddlBerg.SelectedValue %>' OnCommand="lnkEdit_Command">Selecteer</asp:LinkButton>
and in code behind:

Comment: Protected Sub lnkEdit_Command(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs)

        Dim parameters As RouteValueDictionary

        parameters = New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.Bergid = e.CommandArgument})

        Dim vpd As VirtualPathData
        vpd = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(Nothing, "BergenTour", parameters)

    End Sub
: but that does not do the trick. Any solutions?

Comment: Thank you: I will give it a try and will inform you about the outcome!

Comment: I have tried the following according to your advise without any result (no results are shown): first the function - <script type="text/javascript">
    function Navigate() {
        var e = document.getElementById('ddlBerg');
        var selectedId = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var current = window.location.href;
        var theRedirect = current + "?Bergid" + selectedId.toString();
        window.location = theRedirect
    }
</script>

Comment: Second in code-behind page_load:         If Not IsDBNull(Request.QueryString("Bergid")) Then
            doWork(Request.QueryString.Get("Bergid"))
        End If

Comment: Third in code-behind the dowork function:     Protected Function doWork(ByVal selectedID As Integer) As Integer

        ddlBerg.DataBind()
        DetailsView1.DataBind()
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Function
I am doing something wrong because the final result says: no information available. Any ideas?

Comment: PS. Forgot the '=' in the Navigate function, repaired it, makes no difference.

Comment: I tried this by changing a label text from code behind. check if there are any bugs on select for the datatable. that is another topic.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your solution and it worked in the format you gave (so with the asp:label and so on). The problem is that the underlying gridview does not render. This reason behind this must be the navigate function that concentrates on the url (and is working fine). The asp.button does render the gridview but does not show the id, so I am in between solutions to say so. A minor problem furthermore is the fact that clicking the button twice gives a double 'id' adding and thus an error.
The question is: how can the function navigate take care of (also) rendering the gridview besides adapting the url. Again any suggestions are welcome because I am not capable of figuring this out myself (sorry).

Answer (score 0):

I am one step further: in most cases the gridview renders with the following code behind:

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
If Page.IsPostBack() Then
    ddlBerg.DataBind()
    'trying to keep the ddlBerg value
    Me.ddlBerg.SelectedItem.Selected = True
    DetailsView1.DataBind()
    GridView1.DataBind()
End If

If ddlBerg.SelectedValue.Length > 0 Then
    Session("Berg") = ddlBerg.SelectedValue
    Session("Bergnaam") = ddlBerg.SelectedItem.Text
End If

If Not Page.IsPostBack() And Session("Berg") <> "" Then
    ddlBerg.SelectedValue = Session("Berg")
    ddlBerg.DataBind()
    Me.ddlBerg.SelectedItem.Selected = True
    DetailsView1.DataBind()
    GridView1.DataBind()
End If

titel1.Text = "Tour de France: alle Beklimmingen van " + ddlBerg.SelectedItem.Text

If Not IsDBNull(Request.QueryString("Bergid")) Then
    doWork(Request.QueryString("Bergid"))
End If
```

End Sub

Protected Function doWork(ByVal Bergid As Integer) As Integer

```
ddlBerg.SelectedItem.Value = Bergid
ddlBerg.DataBind()
Me.ddlBerg.SelectedItem.Selected = True
DetailsView1.DataBind()
GridView1.DataBind()

lblSelectedId.Text = String.Format("Selected Id of ddlBerg is: {0}", Bergid)
```

End Function

The function navigate() looks like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function navigate() {
        var e = document.getElementById("ddlBerg");
        var selectedID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        //var selectedText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        var current = window.location.href;
        // trying to chop off the ?bergid, but does not work
        var href_split = current.split("?");
        if (href_split > 0) {
            current = href_split[0];
        };
        var togo = current + "?Bergid=" + selectedID.toString();
        //trying to get the name in the url, but query stops working then (because the parameter is bergid)
        //togo = current + "?Bergnaam=" + selectedText.toString();
        window.location = togo
    }
</script>
```

Still I have some problems/wishes:

- I cannot keep the selected ddl value despite the code behind: it jumps back to default every postback
- the bergid is concatenating (?Bergid=45?Bergid=55 etc) which gives an error. My javascript does not solve the problem (split etc)
- I want the name in the url but the problem is that the bergid is the parameter. Perhaps I should change to a name parameter?
- Sometimes the gridview does not render (1st time or 3rd time). When I use the button back arrow in the browser (to avoid concatenating) it mostly works.

I hope there are still some enhancing suggestions possible.